# Any way to programmatically get a list of all applied filters in yadcf?

Tags: yadcf

Is there a way to programmatically get a list of all applied filters in yadcf? Something akin to:

```
var myTable = $('#example').DataTable();

var state = yadcf.getState(myTable);
```

And also, can I go the other way around, that is, I am able to programmatically apply filters? Similar to the following?

```
yadcf.setState(myTable, state);
```

A use case is that when the user updates the filter, I want to be able to store that filter information somewhere (e.g. a URL), so that the user can retrieve it, share it, and another user can view the table in a similar (if not, identical) state that the earlier user saw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [exGetColumnFilterVal](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/beta/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L222) and also for the [exFilterColumn](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/beta/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L214) ,

From docs:

> - exFilterColumn
>               **Description:**        Allows to trigger filter/s externally/programmatically (support ALL filter types!!!) , perfect
>     for showing table with pre filtered columns
>               **Arguments:**          table_arg: (variable of the datatable), 
>                                   array of pairs: column number String/Object with from and to, filter_value (the actual string value that we want to filter by)
>               **Usage example:**      yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [[0, 'Some Data 2']]); //pre filter one column
>                                   yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [[0, 'Some Data 1'], [1, {from: 111, to: 1110}], [2, {from: "", to: "11/25/2014"}]]); //pre filter
>     several columns
>                                   yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [[0, ['Some Data 1','Some Data 2']]]); // for pre filtering multi select filter you should use array
>     with values (or an array with single value)
> - exGetColumnFilterVal
>               **Description:**        Allows to retrieve  column current filtered value (support ALL filter types!!!)
>               **Arguments:**          table_arg: (variable of the datatable), 
>                                   column number:  column number from which we want the value
>               **Usage example:**      yadcf.exGetColumnFilterVal(oTable,1);
>     **Return value:**     String (for simple filter) / Object (for range filter) with from and to properties / Array of strings for multi_select filter

I recommend you to go over the docs (inside the yadcf js file) and read about all yadcf goodies.